# How to use beforeAction in Yii or slug troubles

Tags: php, yii

Yii-jedis!

I'm working on some old Yii-project and must to add to them some features. Yii is quite logical framework but it has some things I couldn't understand. Perhaps I haven't understand Yii-way yet. So I'll describe my problem step-by-step. For impatients - briefly question at the end.

**Intro:** I want to add human-readable URLs to my project. 
Now URLs looks like: *www.site.com/article/359*
And I want them to look like this: *www.site.com/article/how-to-make-pretty-urls*
Very important: old articles must be available on old format URLs, and new - on new URLs.

**Step 1:** First, I've updated rewrite rules in *config/main.php*:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\S+>' => '<controller>/view',
```

And I've added new *texturl* column to article table. So we will store here *human-readable-part-of-url* for new articles. Then I've updated one article with *texturl* for tests.

**Step 2:** Application show articles in *actionView* of *ArticleController* so I've added there this code for preproccessing ID parameter:

```
if (is_numeric($id)) {
    // User try to get /article/359
    $model = $this->loadModel($id); // Article::model()->findByPk($id);
    if ($model->text_url !== null) {
        // If article with ID=359 have text url -> redirect to /article/text-url
        $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->text_url), true, 301);
    }
} else {
    // User try to get /article/text-url
    $model = Article::model()->findByAttributes(array('text_url' => $id));
    $id = ($model !== null) ? $model->id : null ;
}
```

And then begin legacy code:

```
$model = $this->loadModel($id); // Load article by numeric ID
// etc
```

It **works** perfectly! But...

**Step 3:** But we have many actions with ID parameter! What we have to do? Update all actions with that code? I think it's ugly. I've found [CController::beforeAction](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#beforeAction-detail) method. Looks good! So I declare beforeAction and place ID preproccessing there:

```
protected function beforeAction($action) {
    $actionToRun = $action->getId(); 
    $id = Yii::app()->getRequest()->getQuery('id');
    if (is_numeric($id)) {
        $model = $this->loadModel($id);
        if ($model->text_url !== null) {
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->text_url), true, 301);
        } 
    } else {
        $model = Article::model()->findByAttributes(array('text_url' => $id));
        $id = ($model !== null) ? $model->id : null ;
    }
    return parent::beforeAction($action->runWithParams(array('id' => $id)));
}
```

Yes, it works with both URL-formats, but it executes *actionView* **TWICE** and shows page two times! What can I do with this? I've totally confused. Have I choose a right way to solve my problem?

**Briefly:** Can I proceess ID (GET-parameter) before execute of any actions and then run requested action (once!) with modified only ID parameter?

Comment: can you try with blank parameter.. return parent::beforeAction(); What is output?

Comment: @VibhaJ parent::beforeAction() returns 404  
and parent::beforeAction($action) returns 404

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Last line should be:

```
return parent::beforeAction($action);
```

Also to ask you i didnt get your step:3.

As you said you have many controller and you don't need to write code in each file, so you are using beforeAction:
But you have only text_url related to article for all controllers??

```
$model = Article::model()->findByAttributes(array('text_url' => $id));
```

===== updated answer ======

I have changed this function, check now.

If $id is not nummeric then we will find it's id using model and set $_GET['id'], so in further controller it will use that numberic id.

```
protected function beforeAction($action) {          
    $id = Yii::app()->getRequest()->getQuery('id');
    if(!is_numeric($id)) // $id = how-to-make-pretty-urls
    {
        $model = Article::model()->findByAttributes(array('text_url' => $id));
        $_GET['id'] = $model->id ; 
    }
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Comment: No. I have MANY actions with $id parameter in ONE controller (_ArticleController_). Now, these actions gets numeric id as parameter... All that I need is to preprocess this id (from GET) and then run action with it.

Comment: have you checked updated answer and beforeAction function i have added above?

Comment: Old actions code needs to run with numeric $id parameter! So first we must to 'convert' $id from slug format to numeric (_load model by slug and return id_). If we use: `return parent::beforeAction($action);` action will be execute with unchanged $id parameter.

Comment: let your $id is 'how-to-make-pretty-urls' then above code will fetch dependent article id from database and overwrite $id valaue (this code will do it: $_GET['id'] = $model->id ;) to article id. So in article controller even you have 'how-to-make-pretty-urls' in url your controller will ignore it and will use overwritten id which is numeric.

Comment: Yes, your code works, thanks! The most useful was `$_GET['id'] = $model->id ;` - I've totally understand how beforeAction+action works!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I haven't read it all carefully but have you considered using [this extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pcsimpleslugbehavior/)?

Comment: If I saw it before, maybe I would have chosen it for my task :)

Comment: its never too late. I know the extension's author - you should 'buy' it ;-)